# how to add log file for user registration email sent in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

In wordpress project I have added custom email subject and email body when new users are created in admin('wp-admin/users.php') using filter 'wp_new_user_notification_email'.
Now I want to create a log file of email sent when registering new users with data as sent to, email message, sent date time and also whether email is sent or not.

I am not sure where to look for if email sent is success or error when registering new user.

Any help/suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are Multiple Plugins available for Email Logs:

1) https://wordpress.org/plugins/log-emails/

2) https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-log/

3) https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-logging/
With the use of above plugins you can easily manage WordPress Email Logs.

Comment: @PPL is it not possible via plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

In the same filter you're using to change the email contents, you can include a function call to `error_log` where you can write to the error each time an email is filtered, although whether it's sent or not depends on many factors.

Filter the email contents and then immediately do:

```
error_log( 'log_info_goes_here' );
```

Make sure you do this before you `return` the email arguments though otherwise it'll cause issues with the filter hook returning a proper value.

You can also turn on debugging as well, although this might not be the best thing to do on a production environment, but enabling these two constants in your `wp-config.php` file will turn it on.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Lastly, install a logging plugin if you want detailed reports on what is actually happening on your site. There's a couple of decent plugins out there but it's down to opinion on which might suit your needs. Bear in mind that WordPress uses [`wp_mail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) to send email so if you have debugging on, if something goes wrong it'll record the error as part of that function call.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to use the default WordPress debugging for such scenarios. Sometimes developers want to log activities in prod, and for that simple PHP functions can help in creating a simple logger.